# about tensorboard adam node

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

When I run tensorboard, I find in my variable_scope, such as 'weight', there two adam nodes, whose name are 'weight/Adam' and 'weight/Adam_1', but I can't define that in my variable_scope 'weight'. Is my code wrong or the adam algorithm add two nodes in 'weight' automatically in order to make control dependency ?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to create the `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` and an image of the TensorBoard graph visualizer for your model? Also, can you elaborate on what exactly the problem is? The Adam optimizer creates various nodes (e.g. for storing moment vectors and applying the gradient update) but in common use you would not have to manipulate these directly....

Comment: I have the same problem. I am not even sure that this is a problem. Could you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

So first, these 2 nodes are added by your AdamOptimizer, as nodes in the BP calculation graph.

Then for the question why there are two nodes rather than one, tho not understanding what's happening behind the scene, this should be the normal case. Try this simple snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 10), dtype=tf.float64)
W = tf.get_variable(shape=(10, 20), dtype=tf.float64, name="W")
y = tf.matmul(x, W)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.98, epsilon=1e-8)
y_true = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 20), dtype=tf.float64)
loss = y_true - y
train_op = opt.minimize(loss)

for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
    print(v)
```

And this would give you the following:

```
<tf.Variable 'W:0' shape=(10, 20) dtype=float64_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'W/Adam:0' shape=(10, 20) dtype=float64_ref>
<tf.Variable 'W/Adam_1:0' shape=(10, 20) dtype=float64_ref>
```

where also 2 Adam nodes are created